# Ruby count range of values in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and I need to count three separate things.

1) All values less than or equal to `6`.

2) All values equal to `7` or `8`.

3) All values greater than `8`.

What is the best way to do this without counting individual values and adding them all together?

Comment: You mean _add_, or _count frequency_?

Comment: loop through the array once. And do all the operations in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

arr.select {|e| e <= 6}.size
#=> 6

arr.select {|e| e == 7 || e == 8}.size 
#=> 2

arr.select {|e| e > 8}.size 
#=> 2
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way to find the values I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Enumerable#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) with a block.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].count { |val| val <= 6 }
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].count { |val| val == 7 || val == 8 }
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].count { |val| val > 8 }
```

Comment: Loop through three times ??

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d There is more than one way to do it.

Comment: of course more than one way. Wouldn't the fastest/ most efficient be the most interesting way ;)

Answer (score 0):

More interesting, imo, is to answer @Luigi's three questions with a single statement (containing no semicolons). Here are two ways to do it:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

a.inject([0,0,0]) {|arr,i| [arr[0]+(i<7 ? 1:0), arr[1]+((i>6 and i<9) ? 1:0), arr[2]+(i>8 ? 1:0)]}
a.slice_before(7).to_a.map {|arr| arr.slice_before(9).to_a}.flatten(1).map(&:size)
    # => [6, 2, 2]
```

Edit: another, inspired by @staafl's answer:

```
arr.group_by {|e| (e+1)/2-4<=>0}.values.map(&:size)
```

Can you suggest others?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>> hash = Hash.new(0)
>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>> arr.each { |e| hash[(e-7.5).truncate<=>0]+=1 }
>> hash
=> {-1=>6, 0=>2, 1=>2}
```

Or even more succinct:

```
>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>> arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[(e-7.5).truncate<=>0]+=1 }
=> {-1=>6, 0=>2, 1=>2}
```

Comment: These posts are pretty eye opening....I'm new to ruby and seeing all of the many ways to get something done is incredible.

Comment: Clever! And, of course, `.values` => [6,2,2].  You could also write the block as `{|e,h| h[(e+1)/2-4<=>0]+=1}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I believe the order of `.values` is undefined. If an array is required, we should probably use `.values_at(-1,0,1)` to make it explicit, or `.values_at(*-1..1)` if we were being clever :-)

Comment: nice use of integer division btw

Comment: I believe we are OK with v1.9+, as now ["Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted")](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html). BTW, nice use of `values_at`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, hadn't seen that, definitely good to know :-) cheers!